# Explanation on what does this mean: 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

How would you explain in plain English what this piece of code means?

`'post__not_in' => array($post->ID)`

Below is the full context if that helps.

```
// organise our options into a data object
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'orderby' => 'rand',
  'post__not_in' => array($post->ID)
);

// a variable with our query and options
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// do a loop with our new query code
if ($query->have_posts()): while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); ?>

 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
 </a>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This code means that when you use WP_Query to get 3 posts randomly to show related posts or something like that then `'post__not_in' => array($post->ID)` this will exclude the current post from that particular query.